# The computed property "counter" is already defined in data

Tags: vue.js

This is my code

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
   <div id="app">
       <button v-on:click="increase">plus</button>
       <p>Counter : {{ counter }}</p>
       <p>Clicks : {{ clicks }}</p>
    </div>

   <script>
       var app = new Vue({
           el:'#app',
           data:{
               counter : 0,
               clicks : 0
           },
           methods:{
            increase(){
                this.clicks++;

            }        
           },
           computed:{
            counter: function(){
                return this.clicks * 2;
            }

           } 
       });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I click on the button, the counter should double the number of clicks displayed, but it's not working.

This code is working though: [COMPUTED PROPERTIES | VueJS 2 | Learning the Basics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cx2WnT_sckA&index=4&list=PL55RiY5tL51p-YU-Uw90qQH419BM4Iz07).

Comment: When you say it is not working, what exactly is not working? What is it doing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have a `counter` property in your data and you also have a `counter` computed value. To fix your code, just remove the `counter` from data.

```
data:{
  clicks : 0
},
```

This is addressed in the comments of the video you linked. If you notice, he never actually runs the code after he adds the computed.

That said I used his videos and courses as a resource myself when I was starting out. They are for the most part excellent.